# How to get file sizes and extensions from inside a folder to an array

Tags: php, scandir

I searching for a way to get a Array of the Files and Folders inside a Folder with the size and the extension like:

```
$files = array(
  array("foo","txt",18),  # this is foo.txt with 18 bytes
  array("bar","img",513), # this is bar.ing with 513 bytes
  array("baz","",345),    # this is a Folder with 345 bytes inside
);
```

How to solve this? I have tried something like:

```
<?php
  $path = /user";
  $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
  #print_r($files);
?>
```

Comment: can you more clarify ur question.

Comment: Who upvotes badly asked questions like this ___Please stop it___

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to fetch the data for each file in a directory.

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/var/www') as $file) {
    if($file->isDot()) continue;

    $fileinfo[] = [
        $file->getFilename(),
        $file->getExtension(),
        $file->getSize()
    ];

}

print_r($fileinfo);
```

Keep in mind, that a directory is merely a pointer to a list of files so if you want to include the size of that directory as well, you can use a recursive function, check by doing `$file->isDir()` before calculating the size.

```
function getDirContentSize($path){
    $size = 0;
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file){
        if($file->isDot()) continue;
        $size += ($file->isDir()) ? getDirContentSize("$path/$file") : $file->getSize();
    }

    return $size;
}
```

Comment: but it return not the right size of a folder with files inside

Comment: That's because its returning the size of the fs node, not the size of the contents of the directory. You could transform it into a recursive function checking with `isDir()`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $path = "/user";
 $filepath = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
 $files = array();

 foreach($filepath as $k=>$v) {
   $files[] =$v;
   $files[] = filesize($v);
   $files[] = pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

Comment: Like this: But not this, as it does not distinguish files from directories and therefore generates errors, and also generate 3 entries in the `$files` array for each file!

Answer (score 0):

[Filepath](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.pathinfo.php) and [filesize](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filesize.php) will give you the informations you need.

Try this :

```
<?php
    $path = __DIR__;
    $files_info = array();
    $i = 0;

    if(is_dir($path)){
        $dh = opendir($path);
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
            $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);

            if($pathinfo["filename"] != '' and $pathinfo["filename"] != '.'){
                $files_info[$i] = array($pathinfo["filename"], $pathinfo["extension"], filesize($file));
                $i++;
            }
        }

        var_dump($files_info);
    }
?>
```